# Fix strange 2px gaps before heading tags

Tags: html, css, margin, html-heading

I've been working on a project for a client and all was going okay until I noticed that my h1/h2/h3 (any heading tag) had shifted to the right 2/3px. They may have been doing that the whole time, but I only just noticed. The gaps can be seen fairly clearly when you highlight in devtools (see example further down)

Has anyone noticed this before or come across it? Googling has been hard as whenever you ask about spaces before and after, the answers are all about space above and below, not before the text starts. I've tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE and the issue is the same. I've got around it by putting in a left: -2px hack but it's not nice to leave it like that and I'm also curious to see why. Looking at it, I thought it might be something to do with the -webkit-margin-before property that was being set but even clearing that with !important doesn't fix it. I also tried using the necolas normalize css file to see if that helped, but nothing happened. I'm using styles that I inherited from a bigger project (and adding my own) but haven't seen anything like this before. (Or perhaps just never noticed it...)

It also only seems to be on the first letter of the h tag - so on this multi-line example:

[second example showing multi-line h tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nukoj.png)

The space only appears before the first letter and the next lines are fine.

I've pasted a shot of the computed styles on the h2 tag - and you should be able to see the gap when you see the text highlighted on the right.

[computed styles and another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4wpW.png)

A bit stumped, and looking for some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely due to the rendering of the font itself (something you cannot really interact with). You may want to check the behaviour on different browsers, as it could differ slightly.

With that said, here's a ghetto workaround which you might find handy. It involves using the text-indent property:

```
.test {
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  top:100px;
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:30px;
  text-indent:-50px;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rdo471dg/